# Understanding Listview in Winforms for Powershell

Tags: listview

Hi I have only just got around to taking a look at the Listview class in Winforms.

The code I have below is just a test to see how to display data.

I would like a Column of AD Users, which I can seem to get, but also I would like a Column of Groups.
As you will be able to see I have set the two columns, one with checkboxes and one without currently. I thought I could call the column by name and fill them in. Maybe I am using the wrong view? I have set it to details.

Or does Listview details work by rows rather than columns?

I have a variation of this program using CheckboxLists that works perfectly and is used for AD User Group Addition/Removal depending on what user you choose (shows you what groups the selected user is already a member of 1st).

Is anyone able to help me understand the multiple columns work, I looked on MSDN, hard mentally to decrypt in places, I'm not a C# programmer, starting to pick things up though, seems close to P'shell as it appears to built on top of it(.Net).

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Drawing"
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

Clear-Host

#   Create a New Form
    $form=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.topmost=$true
    $form.Text="Add/Remove AD User to And From Groups"
    $form.Location.x=400
    $form.Location.Y=400
    $form.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(665,330)
#   Now Lock the form so it cannot be re-sized.
    $Form.MaximumSize=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(665,330)
    $Form.MinimumSize=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(665,330)
#   Group Text Label
    $Grouplbl1=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.label
    $Grouplbl1.Location=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,2)
    $FontFace = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Comic Sans MS",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
    $Grouplbl1.Font=$FontFace
    $Grouplbl1.text="AD User List"
# AN INSTANCE OF THE LISTVIEW CLASS IS CREATED (THIS IS THE LISTVIEW CONTROL)       
    $Listview = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView 
    $Listview.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(3,25)
    $Listview.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,256)
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma",8,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::regular)
    $Listview.Font=$Font
    $Listview.CheckBoxes=$true
    $Listview.Name="Main"
    $Listview.AutoArrange=$true
    $Listview.GridLines=$true
    $Listview.MultiSelect=$false
    $listView.View = "Details"
    $Listview.backcolor = "Black"
    $Listview.forecolor = "LightGreen"

    # Populate the User CheckboxList
    #$listview.columns.AddRange('AD User List','AD Group List')
    $listView.Columns.Add("AD User list")
    $listView.Columns[0].Width = -2
    $AllADUsers=Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties name -SearchBase "OU=TS Tech Users,DC=smallhome,DC=local" |`
    sort name |select Name
    $AllADUsers.name | ForEach-Object{[void]$Listview.items.Add("AD User list").SubItems.Add($_)}
    
    $listView.Columns.Add("AD GroupList")
    
    $listView.Columns[1].Width = -2
    $AllADGroups=Get-ADGroup -Filter * | select name | Sort Name
    $AllADGroups.name | ForEach-Object{[void]$Listview.items.Add("AD Grouplist").SubItems.Add($_)}
    $form.Controls.add($Listview)

$form.ShowDialog()
```

[image: Output of Code]

Answer (score 0):

I have now worked out how to use the listview and set the subitems, along with the 'setindexchanged' and it does indeed use rows for selecting of data. I have only used the list and details views. One slight anomaly I have found with my change of index is that if I run the program/script the first time I select a record, I can get a messagebox with a name just once. If I then select a different record the messagebox I have reads the same record twice!! It doesn't matter which other record I read I still get a record read twice. If I restart script the first one I choose gets read once, weird or what!! Unless I'm supposed to reset something.... My initial idea for this how ever does not work so I had to think of doing something different, which I now have and it was this that helped me work things out, along with alot of searching and learning a little bit of c# along the way!